# How do you delete Google Calendar goals?

Tags: google-calendar

A quick Google search pointed me to [this thread on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/androidapps/comments/4fcm5z/how_to_remove_google_calendar_goals/)

Following a link posted in the comments, and then going to the "android" tab (which I totally missed at first) [I found these instructions](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6334090)

1. Open the Google Calendar app.
2. Tap the session.
3. In the top right, tap More.
4. Tap Delete > This session or All following sessions (and stop scheduling).
5. Tap OK.

I'm just wondering where I would find "This session" or "All following sessions", because I don't see it:

[image: where, google calendar, is delete this stupid event!]

I'm using Calendar Version 5.5.15-129963483-release and I thought I might be out of date but there doesn't appear to be a newer version on the Play Store.

Comment: If you click 'delete' does it give you those options?

Comment: Nope, it just deletes the single event. Repeat *ad nauseum* for every *bleeping* event in each "goal". Ugh. Obviously I'm a bit frustrated @ Google (Calendar) right now

Comment: I've just tried myself and I get a prompt to delete 'All following sessions'. The event itself looks different to your screenshot though, mine includes 'Session' information and rather than 'Going?' at the bottom it has 'Defer' and 'Mark as Done'. Are you sure these events were added via Goals?

Comment: @bmdixon I'm sure they were originally. They pop up as if they were goals, i.e. they have the option to mark as done, defer, etc. I think something got horked up when I was doing something else.

Comment: Two points (which worked for me): first, where it says in step 2, "tap the session", it means tap the goal. And second, this does only work in the mobile app, not the desktop/browser calendar. I appreciate this may not help with Wayne's problem, but it helped me as I tried to delete goal entries (especially the second point), and when I too had found docs like he shared (and this discussion). After finding this (https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/1067516?msgid=5603332), I wanted to clarify things here for others who may find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same Calendar Version as yours ( update released on 15/08/2016). Moto X Play 6.0.1

I created goals using goals option of app and am able to choose and delete. Screenshots below

- First one shows goals for today and tomorrow
- On pressing one of them it appears as in second one
- Third one shows the *Delete* option on pressing the overflow (3 button) menu
- Last one shows the options you are looking for

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is perhaps by deleting part of the goal via calendar or something else it screwed things up and just turned them into regular events. I just manually went through and deleted them all.

Answer (score 2):

I found another solution that works if you're just get shown to delete single event. It is essential to get the picture shown of how often you participate.

1. Go in Google Calendar on your desktop
2. Click on old goal dates and press “Did it”
3. Now go to the Google Calendar App
4. Press on the 3 dots on the start screen of the app and actualize your calendar
5. Afterwards click on the actual event/goal and go to the 3 dots
6. Now you can choose to “Delete all further events”

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The circled one means Access and Settings. After that a new page will open. At the bottom of the page will be a blue button saying "Delete all the calendar". The only solution I found to delete the "forever" events. That button will delete all your appointments or events. but at least it works

Answer (score 0):

You might be using the Android calendar App that comes by default (it shows all the other calendars, Google, Samsun, Phone, Outlook, etc), be sure you use the Google Calendar, I had the same problem until I realized it was the wrong app.